# What is the best way to move sql-linked methods of entities from a data context to entitiy class?

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, datacontext

I like EntityFramework. Usually I create a service class (layout) to put there the logic of interaction with a database. It looks like this:

```
public class UserService
{
    MyDbContext _context;

    public UserService(MyDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void MoveUserToGroup(User user, Group group)) { ... }
}
```

And I use that so somewhere in my code:

```
userService.MoveUserToGroup(User user, Group group);
```

It's good, but I would like my classes to look like this:

```
public class User
{
    // ...
    public void AddTo(Group group) { ... }
}

public class Group
{
    // ...
    public void Add(User user) { ... }
}
```

And I want to use that so:

```
user.AddToGroup(group);
```

What is the best way to do it? DI? Extensions? How to keep database context across my classes?

Comment: This is a problem that should be solved by the OR/M of your choice not by DI.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually map all the related navigational properties of an entity.

```
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public void AddTo(Group group) 
    { 
       Groups.Add(group);
    }
}
```